# I need to get these arrays that are passing in just one variable, to play in the blade but when I do the foreach it only gets from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, controller

I need to get these arrays that are passing in just one variable, to play in the blade but when I do the foreach it only gets from an array,when I make the request it only brings me an array in the view and I would like to bring them all.

```
Array
(
    [0] => TESTE FILIPINHO
)
Array
(
    [0] => Carlos Sebastião Thomas Gomes
)
Array
(
    [0] => ANYMARKET PEDIDO TESTE
)
```

how i would like it to be

```
Array
(
    [1] => TESTE FILIPINHO
    [2] => Carlos Sebastião Thomas Gomes
    [3] => ANYMARKET PEDIDO TESTE
)
```

my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $login_ok = DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->first();
        $id_tray = $login_ok->id_tray;
        $consumer_key = env('consumer_key');
        $consumer_secret = env('consumer_secret');
        $code = env('code');
        $api_address = env('api_address');

        $acesso = Http::post($api_address.'/auth', [
            'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
            'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
            'code' => $code
        ]);
        $token = $acesso["access_token"];
        $response = Http::get($api_address.'/orders', [
            'access_token' => $token,
            'partner_id' => $id_tray,
        ]);
        $pedidos = $response["Orders"];
        $pedidos2 = "";
          for ($i=0; $i < count($pedidos) ; $i++) { 
            $id_pedidos = $pedidos[$i]['Order']['customer_id'];
            $cliente = Http::get($api_address.'/customers/'.$id_pedidos, [
                'access_token' => $token,
                ':id' => $id_pedidos,
                
            ]);
            $usuario = $cliente['Customer']['name'];
            $exibirindicado2 = array($usuario); 
            $result = array_unique($exibirindicado2);  
            print_r($result);  
            
        }
       /*  foreach ($pedidos as $idcliente) {
            $cliente_id = $idcliente['Order']['customer_id'];
            
            $cliente = Http::get($api_address.'/customers/'.$cliente_id, [
                'access_token' => $token,
                ':id' => $cliente_id,
                
            ]);
            $Customer = $cliente["Customer"];
            dd( $pedidos);
        } */
        
        
        //print_r( $Customer);
        
     
     
        
        
        return view('pages.minhas-vendas',compact('id','pedidos','result'));
```

follow below my view

```
@foreach ($result as $result)
                                    <td>{{ $result }}</td>    
                                    @endforeach
```

I only need to join the arrays so that I can pull the view with these three names but I can't if anyone can help me I'll be grateful

Answer (score 0):

@jhow-costa it is hard to understand what exactly is the problem and what do you want to do.

Please reply explaining what this means:

> when I make the request it only brings me an array in the view and I would like to bring them all

Try this:

**CONTROLLER**

```
    return View::make('pages.rede',compact('user','indicados','nivel2','nivel3','nivel4')));
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
 @if(!empty($nivel2))
    @foreach ($nivel2 as $user) {
```

And access the `$user` data with the object accessor (`$user->attribute`)

If by your comment you are saying that you would want to have the whole data nested like below:

```
    $indicados = [
        [ // nivel2
           'firstname' => '',
           ...
            'children' => [
                [ // nivel3
                 'firstname' => '',
                  ...
                  'children' => [
                     [ // nivel4
                        'firstname' => '',
                         ...
                     ],
                  ],
                ],
             ],
         ],
     ];
```

You will need to handle on the controller side.

### General (Unrelated to the question) comments about the code

It seems like you are trying to build a Multi-level Marketing type of relationship. That's a tree data structure:

Each user has a single parent (or no parents if they are the root) and can have multiple children.

Your design is not efficient and if you start to get a big number of users your application will run into issues quickly.

If the user has 2 on nivel2, and each user on the nivel2 has 2 other users on the next level and so on, until nivel4, your application will make 7 requests to the database.

My advice:

- Take a look at this article about possible designs for similar use cases. Without it you will always be suffering to handle the queries

  - https://www.baeldung.com/cs/storing-tree-in-rdb
- Re-do your page to not pull all levels at once, but maybe 2-3 levels. and make a new request (e.g. ajax request) to grab more levels on user request.

Querying all relationships can start to be a problem if you have too many levels (as you are storing the whole data in memory).

- Reduce the amount of data returned by user to only include what you need

```
DB::table('users')->where('indicado',$id_tray)->get(['firstname'])
```

- Reduce the number of queries by returning relationships in a single query (hard to do without changing your database schemas and relationships)

### What about the code

There are too many things that look off on your logic / design and that could be improved.

I will not extend myself here as I don't even know what your goal is.
But you can ask me here or in a DM to go over those points.

Comment: I answered your question above

Comment: There is no "above" with Stack Overflow answers.  The answers are re-ordered for a number of reasons.  Answers should not seek clarifications.  If a question is not clear, it should not be answered.  If a user has insufficient rep to post comments under the question, they are expected to leave the page untouched and focus only on pages that are clear.  New users must not circumvent the permission rules by posting answers with requests for clarification.

Comment: @JhowCosta, I am trying to help you out.
Your question is not that specific for someone that doesn't know the business logic like you do. 

I sent a proposed change that can fix the "only brings me an array in the view and I would like to bring them all." issue. 

You didn't reply if that resolved the issue, nor gave more details as asked. 
If you are not willing to send more info / feedback on the answer then you are on your own.

Comment: @cauesilva It did help me in the code cleaning part but in the functional part I didn't edit the question and put cleaner information about the question itself, thanks

Comment: @JhowCosta, great. 
You changed considerably the code. That's good. Without seeing how is the data structure returned from `$response` and  `$cliente`. 

But the issue you are facing is: you are not storing the clientes in an array that was defined outside of the loop. Besides, for `$usuario = $cliente['Customer']['name'];` I imagine that only a single user is returned from each api call, is that right? 

If that is the case you can do:

Comment: - Before the for loop create an empty array `$result = []`

- Instead of assigning `$result = array_unique($exibirindicado2);` you do two things: 

- Check if the value was already added to the $result array:
- If not, then add the new $exibirindicado2 to it:

`if (!in_array($exibirindicado2)) { $result[] = $exibirindicado2; }`

Comment: Now, that solves the problem with the logic error you mentioned. In the high level I would comment: Is the API a third party or yours? If it is yours, write an api method to return everything you need in a single call (instead of making multiple http requests).  If it doesn't write a Service to handle the data fetching and transformations. The controller should be an orchestrator: receive a request, call other classes that do the leg work and return something. - And you are not handling edge cases: what if the api request times out? what if returns an error?

Comment: $usuario it brings more than one user of the $cliente, but for me it didn't work your solution keeps returning me Array
(
    [0] => TESTE FILIPINHO
)
Array
(
    [0] => Carlos Sebastião Thomas Gomes
)
Array
(
    [0] => ANYMARKET PEDIDO TESTE
)

Comment: But now I see: your line  `$exibirindicado2 = array($usuario);` is creating a new array for each user, that's why you see three arrays with only one element for each user. 

change your code to: `$usuario = $cliente['Customer']['name'];` `$result[] = $usuario`

You should now, with your last example get: `Array ([0] => TESTE FILIPINHO [1] => Carlos Sebastião Thomas Gomes  [2] => ANYMARKET PEDIDO TESTE)`

Comment: @JhowCosta, can you confirm the code change in my last comment fix your issue?